# InvalidArgument=Value of '1' is not valid for 'index'

Tags: c#, ms-access

I have an error in my C# application that interacts with MDB access DB.

The error is:

> InvalidArgument=Value of '1' is not valid for 'index'.

My code:

```
objConn.Open();
listView1.Items.Clear();
OleDbCommand cmd = new OleDbCommand("select a.bill_Id,a.bill_Number,a.bill_Date,c.sup_Name,Sum(b.de_NetPrice),a.bill_Note from (suppliers c right JOIN bills a on c.sup_Id = a.bill_From) LEFT JOIN  bill_Details b on a.bill_Id = b.bill_Id where a.bill_Id like '%" + txbSearch.Text + "%' or a.bill_Number like '%" + txbSearch.Text + "%' or c.sup_Name like '%" + txbSearch.Text + "%' or a.bill_Note like '%" + txbSearch.Text + "%'  group by a.bill_Id,a.bill_Number,a.bill_Date,c.sup_Name,a.bill_Note order by a.bill_Date desc", objConn);
OleDbDataReader dataReader = cmd.ExecuteReader();

int i = 0;
while (dataReader.Read())
{
    DateTime dt0 = DateTime.Parse(dataReader.GetValue(2).ToString());
    int Date1 = DateTime.Compare(DateTime.Parse(dt0.ToShortDateString()), DateTime.Parse(txbFrom.Value.ToShortDateString()));
    int Date2 = DateTime.Compare(DateTime.Parse(dt0.ToShortDateString()), DateTime.Parse(txbTo.Value.ToShortDateString()));
    if (Date1 >= 0 && Date2 <= 0)
    {
        listView1.Items.Add(dataReader.GetValue(0).ToString());

        // The error happens on the following line
        listView1.Items[i].SubItems.Add(dataReader.GetValue(1).ToString());

        listView1.Items[i].SubItems.Add(dt0.ToShortDateString());
        listView1.Items[i].SubItems.Add(dataReader.IsDBNull(3) ? "0" : dataReader.GetString(3));
        listView1.Items[i].SubItems.Add(dataReader.IsDBNull(4) ? "0" : dataReader.GetDouble(4).ToString("n2"));
        listView1.Items[i].SubItems.Add(dataReader.IsDBNull(5) ? "-" : dataReader.GetString(5));
    }

    i++;
}

objConn.Close();
```

The listview has these columns:
ID -- Number -- BillDate -- Supplier -- total -- Note

Comment: `(dataReader.GetValue(1) ?? String.Empty).ToString() `   See if that helps

Comment: @bill, no not null !

Comment: If accessing slot 1 is giving you the error, can you step through with a debugger and look at the `dataReader` object to make sure it has what you need in it?

Comment: @BenKnoble thats the confusing part, if accessing slot 1 is causing the crash how is he able to access slot 2 a few lines before without a crash. I assumed that 1 was just null, but he said it isn't null.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I may have found the issue.

If first time around the 'if (Date1 >= 0 && Date2 <= 0)' statemant evaluates to false, the i index will still get incremented. And then on the second iteration the if statement might evaluate to true, and then your index will be off-by-one, as there is just one Item in the ListView, but you try to get at using listView1.Items[1], instead of listView1.Items[0], which would be correct.

Solution would be to change the code to:

```
if (Date1 >= 0 && Date2 <= 0)
{
    listView1.Items.Add(dataReader.GetValue(0).ToString());
    listView1.Items[i].SubItems.Add(dataReader.GetValue(1).ToString());// The error appears on this line

    listView1.Items[i].SubItems.Add(dt0.ToShortDateString());
    listView1.Items[i].SubItems.Add(dataReader.IsDBNull(3) ? "0" : dataReader.GetString(3));
    listView1.Items[i].SubItems.Add(dataReader.IsDBNull(4) ? "0" : dataReader.GetDouble(4).ToString("n2"));
    listView1.Items[i].SubItems.Add(dataReader.IsDBNull(5) ? "-" : dataReader.GetString(5));
    i++;
}
```